# Wait till first method is executed in all threads till execute second

Tags: java, multithreading

I have a small demo code where I have a Bean class and BeanRegister class. Bean class has two methods which are `preInit()` and `postInit()`. And BeanRegister is a thread class which has Bean class as a field. Here my code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Bean beanA = new Bean();

    BeanRegister beanRegister1 = new BeanRegister(beanA);
    BeanRegister beanRegister2 = new BeanRegister(beanA);

    beanRegister1.start();
    beanRegister2.start();
}

private static class BeanRegister extends Thread {
    private final Bean bean;

    public BeanRegister(Bean bean) {
        this.bean = bean;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            bean.preInit();
            bean.postInit();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}

private static class Bean {

    public void preInit() throws InterruptedException {
        Thread.sleep(new Random().nextInt(1000) * 5);
        System.out.println("PreInit +" + Thread.currentThread().getName());
    }

    public void postInit() throws InterruptedException {
        System.out.println("PostInit +" + Thread.currentThread().getName());
    }
}
```

The problem I faced, is locking. I want to lock `postInit()` in all threads, before those execution of `preInit()` method in those threads is not finished. So, when all threads finished execution of `preInit()`, then I want to allow threads to execute `postInit()`. Any ideas how to do it in proper way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a `CountDownLatch` which is shared across all threads.

Some theory first: what is a [CountDownLatch](https://www.baeldung.com/java-countdown-latch)?

It's a very simple concurrent utility which you initialize with a certain integer, let's say N. It then offers you two methods:

- `countdown()` => it will decrease to `N-1` each time that is called
- `await()` => it will stop the current thread until when the count of the countdown is zero (you can specify a timeout if wished).

Of course, the great advantage of this class is that race conditions are handled for you (when you call `countdown()` or `await()` from a certain thread, you are guaranteed that other threads will see what's happening without you handling any memory barrier).

So now, based on your code, you start by making the `preInit` and `postInit` methods of `Bean` taking a `CountDownLatch` in parameter:

```
private static class Bean {

    public void preInit(CountDownLatch latch) throws InterruptedException {
        Thread.sleep(new Random().nextInt(1000) * 5);
        System.out.println("PreInit +" + Thread.currentThread().getName());
        latch.countDown(); //<-- each time one preInit ends, decrease the countdown by 1
    }

    public void postInit(CountDownLatch latch) throws InterruptedException {
        latch.await(); //<-- even if you're called here, wait until when the countdown is at zero before starting execution
        System.out.println("PostInit +" + Thread.currentThread().getName());
    }
}
```

Specifically, the `preInit` will count it down, while the `postInit` will `await` for it to be at zero before actually starting.

Then, in your calling function you create a `new CountDownLatch(2)` (where `2` is the number of independent threads) and you simply push it down in the call stack:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Bean beanA = new Bean();

    CountDownLatch latch = new CountDownLatch(2);
    BeanRegister beanRegister1 = new BeanRegister(beanA, latch);
    BeanRegister beanRegister2 = new BeanRegister(beanA, latch);

    beanRegister1.start();
    beanRegister2.start();
}

private static class BeanRegister extends Thread {
    private final Bean bean;
    private final CountDownLatch latch;

    public BeanRegister(Bean bean, CountDownLatch latch) {
        this.bean = bean;
        this.latch = latch;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            bean.preInit(latch);
            bean.postInit(latch);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Sample output:

```
PreInit +Thread-1
PreInit +Thread-0
PostInit +Thread-1
PostInit +Thread-0

Process finished with exit code 0
```